# Issue with elevatr::get_elev_raster: "Please Connect to the Internet and Try Again" Error

Tags: r, geospatial, terra, elevatr

I'm encountering an issue with the elevatr::get_elev_raster function in R, specifically receiving a 'Please connect to the internet', despite having a functional internet connection as confirmed by successfully using download.file.

The code I am running is

```
 library(elevatr)
 library(sf)
 data(lake)
 lake_buff  <- st_buffer(lake, 1000)
 loc_df <- data.frame(x = runif(6,min=sf::st_bbox(lake)$xmin, 
                               max=sf::st_bbox(lake)$xmax),
                   y = runif(6,min=sf::st_bbox(lake)$ymin, 
                                max=sf::st_bbox(lake)$ymax))
                                
 x <- get_elev_raster(locations = loc_df, prj = st_crs(lake) , z=10)
 x <- get_elev_raster(lake, z = 12)
 x <- get_elev_raster(lake, src = "gl3", expand = 5000)
x <- get_elev_raster(lake_buff, z = 10, clip = "locations")
```

I've tried updating the elevatr package and checked my firewall settings, but the issue persists. The exact error message is: 'Please connect to the internet and try again.' I am looking for guidance on why this error is occurring and any potential solutions. My session information, as obtained by sessionInfo(), is included.

Comment: try this simple code to debug and check if R has access to the internet: download.file("https://www.google.com", destfile = "test.html", method = "libcurl")

Comment: The `elevatr` [source](https://github.com/jhollist/elevatr/blob/7b11c909df8838a93aaabfc3f247a804e91a5fdd/R/get_elev_raster.R#L90) indicates that this error occurs when `curl::has_internet())` is `FALSE`, i.e. you can rule out any problems with your code or server issues. Your R session simply cannot connect to the internet. If this is at home it will be a router/firewall issue and if it's a corporate environment speak to your IT department.